# NoSuchMethodError when invoking RedisOperationsSessionRepository.delete

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-redis, spring-session

I'm using Spring Session and Spring Data Redis for session management. I haven't used Spring Boot.

Used are as follows:

```
spring-session: 1.3.5.RELEASE
spring-data-redis: 2.1.4.RELEASE
spring-webmvc: 5.0.4.RELEASE
lettuce-core: 5.1.4.RELEASE
```

Included these beans for Redis configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class HttpSessionConfig extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory();                // redis configuration
    }

    @Bean
    public static ConfigureRedisAction configureRedisAction() {
        return ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        template.setKeySerializer( new StringRedisSerializer() );
        template.setHashValueSerializer( new GenericToStringSerializer< Object >( Object.class ) );
        template.setValueSerializer( new GenericToStringSerializer< Object >( Object.class ) );
        return template;
    }

}
```

But I got the following error frequently:

```
ERROR org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisOperations.delete(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisSessionExpirationPolicy.cleanExpiredSessions(RedisSessionExpirationPolicy.java:132) ~[spring-session-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.cleanupExpiredSessions(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:398) ~[spring-session-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) [spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_201]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_201]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_201]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_201]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_201]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_201]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_201]
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22538

Answer (score 0):

You should downgrade spring-data-redis version below 2.0.0.REALESE. After 2.0.0 version there are no void delete(K key).